# Has Three.js setHSL() been deprecated?

Tags: javascript, colors, three.js

I'm looking for any way possible to implement an HSL color scheme in my threejs project. I don't see anything after 2013 in the documentation that implements the .setHSL() or .offsetHSL().

What is the best/easiest way to use only HSL in a threejs scene?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `.setHSL ( h, s, l )` `this`
>
> h — hue value between 0.0 and 1.0
>   s — saturation value between 0.0 and 1.0
>   l — lightness value between 0.0 and 1.0
>
> Sets color from hsl
>
> ---
>
> `.getHSL ()` `hsl`
>
> Returns an object with properties h, s, and l.
>
> ---
>
> `.offsetHSL ( h, s, l )` `this`
>
> Adds given h, s, and l to this color's existing h, s, and l values.

[three.js - reference - color](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Color)

```js
var color = new THREE.Color();
color.setHSL( .74, .64, .59 );
console.log('HSL Object:', color.getHSL());
console.log('Hex String:', color.getHexString());
console.log('RGB:', color.getStyle());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r79/three.js"></script>
```